# Is it possible to delay a query in a sheet for 10 seconds so that data in another sheet can have enought time to load?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've Sheet1 and Sheet2. I want a query in Sheet1 (at cell D1) to be delayed by 10 seconds so that Sheet2 can have enough time to load. Essentially, I do not want Sheet1's D1 cell to load a value unless Sheet2 is completed done getting news feeds.

Comment: I'm still very new to stack so am still exploring its features. hence there's all the edits

Comment: Please don't add meta commentary to the question. If you want to contact player0, comment below one of their posts or start a new chat room with player0 here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/5632629/player0

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Comment: Have you considered using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) with a sleep function and cast the Query after that?

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this first and see how it works for you:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuFmQ.png]

```
=IFERROR(NOW()/0, IF(AND(Sheet2!A1<>"NO NEWS FOUND", Sheet2!F1 > Sheet2!F13), Sheet2!F2, 
 IF(AND(Sheet2!A13<>"NO NEWS FOUND", Sheet2!A1="NO NEWS FOUND"), Sheet2!F14, 
 IF(Sheet2!F1 = Sheet2!F13, Sheet2!F2, "None"))))
```

Comment: I thought OP was trying to loosen the workload on his sheet. Wouldn't this actually increase the load?

Comment: @TheMaster could be true. I just suspected it is not about workload but a delay of feeds causing a brief miscalculation till it catches up

Comment: Hello - I do not want the whole Sheet1 to render after Sheet2 is complete. I just want Cell D1 in Sheet1 to render after Sheet2 is complete. Is that possible? Thank you for your help so far !